# java version and javac version are different in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: java, ubuntu

Will this create any problem?

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.10 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
$ javac --version
javac 15.0.1
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L95Vx.png)

Comment: Possibly .. you might be able to use -target=11 to force to a compatible version for the JRE... (check exact syntax with `javac -help`)

Comment: So, you're suggesting me that Java and Javac version will be the same. And how do I downgrade the javac version 15 to 11?

Comment: you don't need to downgrade - its about byte-code formats (well and libraries too I guess) - the -target option say compile like you were javac 11.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing using the console, the answer is: most possibly, yes. Learn and use something like `jenv` to better use java at the console. Check [this article](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-manage-multiple-java-versions-with-jenv-on-linux/).